# arrange a list of dicts based on some elements of dict

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries with 5 elements each and I need to order this list based on 2 elements of each dict in the list. The 2 elements can take 3 values.

Here's an example:

```
list = [{ 'm' : '3', 'n', : '3', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '3'}, { 'm' : '5', 'n', : '2', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '1'}, { 'm' : '3', 'n', : '1', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '1'}, { 'm' : '3', 'n', : '3', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '2'}]
```

so the list order is based on 2 elements  n and p which can take 3 values (1 2 and 3):
1. if n and p is 1 then those elements should be placed first
2. if n = 1 and p = 2 then those are placed next
3. if n = 1 and p = 3 then those are placed next
4. if p = 1 and n = 2 then those are placed next
5. and finally if p = 1 and n = 3 those are placed next
6. and last is p and n is 3

final list would be in this case:

```
final_list = [{ 'm' : '3', 'n', : '1', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '1'}, { 'm' : '5', 'n', : '2', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '1'}, { 'm' : '3', 'n', : '3', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '2'}, { 'm' : '3', 'n', : '3', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '3'}]
```

Can some one give me the best solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

For putting lists into a particular order, used the `sorted()` builtin function or the `list.sort()` method. For specifying an unusual order, use the `key=` argument to either of those functions. Here is one such call that might work for you:

```
result = sorted(list, key=lambda x: (x['n'], x['p']))
```

Aside: don't use builtin type names as variable names. Doing so will likely lead to confusion later.

Example program:

```
list_ = [{ 'm' : '3', 'n' : '3', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '3'},
        { 'm' : '5', 'n' : '2', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '1'},
        { 'm' : '3', 'n' : '1', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '1'},
        { 'm' : '3', 'n' : '3', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '2'}]

final_list = [{ 'm' : '3', 'n' : '1', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '1'},
              { 'm' : '5', 'n' : '2', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '1'},
              { 'm' : '3', 'n' : '3', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '2'},
              { 'm' : '3', 'n' : '3', 'o' : '7', 'p' : '3'}]

result = sorted(list_, key=lambda x: (x['n'], x['p']))
assert result == final_list
```

Comment: what if n and p are not numbers ?

Comment: `n` and `p` are not numbers in your example; they are strings. Regardless of their type, the  results of the `key` function are compared using the `<` operator.